# Wordpress - Max. characters for latest post titles

Tags: wordpress, title

On the homepage of my new website (http://tinyurl.com/q53ccn8) I am displaying recents posts under my news slider (header = Nieuws).

I do this with the following code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'offset' => 6,); $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args ); foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ echo '<li class="list-group-item"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';}?>
```

Now, I would like to cut of the title of the recent post with ... after 40 characters (including space) so every title sticks to one line. How can I do this in the code I use above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shorten my title lenth by characters via php code wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413712/how-to-shorten-my-title-lenth-by-characters-via-php-code-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do this with css for example:

```
.textDiv{
   line-height: 10px;
   height: 12px;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 12px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

So basically you are creating a div with max dimensions (max-height/ width) and if there is a overflow, hide it and display ... (ellipsis)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. I never knew this css function exist.